# How to unselect button on click in a Bootstrap btn-group?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try to make a Bootstrap btn-group unselectable by clicking on a previously selected button with the following code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('label.btn').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="note_reactivity" class="btn-group notes" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id="1" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio">1
  </label>
  <label id="2" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio">2
  </label>
  <label id="3" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio">3
  </label>
  <label id="4" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio">4
  </label>
</div>
```

The "active" class seems to be removed by my code on the click event but it reappears just after.
Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because there is still the underlying Bootstrap click event handler attached to the element that will put the `active` class back on the element right after you take it off. To get around this you can set a tiny delay on your code to ensure it happens after Bootstrap does it's own thing.

Also note that you need to manually de-select the underlying radio button as well as remove the class. Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-group').on('click', 'label.btn', function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active').find('input').prop('checked', false);
      }.bind(this), 10);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="note_reactivity" class="btn-group notes" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label id="1" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio">1
  </label>
  <label id="2" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio">2
  </label>
  <label id="3" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio">3
  </label>
  <label id="4" class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio">4
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Worked for me too.  This makes me both very happy and very sad that it's so hard.  :-)